# How do I run just a single stage in my bamboo build?

Tags: bamboo

I have a bamboo build with 2 stages: Build&Test and Publish.  The way bamboo works, if Build&Test fails, Publish is not run.  This is usually the way that I want things.

However, sometimes, Build&Test will fail, but I still want Publish to run. Typically, this is a manual process where even though there is a failing test, I want to push a button so that I can just run the Publish stage.

In the past, I had two separate plans, but I want to keep them together as one.  Is this possible?

Comment: Would also be good for testing. No need to rerun all stages if I just changed a parameter to the last stage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Atlassian help forum, here:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/52863/how-do-i-run-just-a-single-stage-of-a-build

> Short answer: no. If you want to run a stage, all prior stages have to finish successfully, sorry.
>
> What you could do is to use the Quarantine functionality, but that involves re-running the failed job (in yet-unreleased Bamboo 4.1, you may have to press "Show more" on the build result screen to see the re-run button).
>
> Another thing that could be helpful in such situation (but not for OP) is disabling jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the best solution to most Bamboo problems is to rely on Bamboo as little as possible because you ultimately can't patch it.

In this case, I would just quickly write / re-use a aynchronous dependency resolution mechanism (something like GNU Make and its targets), and run that from a single stage.

Then just run everything on the default `all`-like target, and let users select the target on a custom run variable.